# d3.js loading csv files with ISO-8859-1 encoding

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm trying to parse csv files that are ISO-8859-1 encoded with d3.js. Ascended characters break.

I know converting the file to UTF-8 would solve the problem. This is not an option in this case.

Is there a way of reading these files correctly somehow? Re-coding them with javascript would work if that is possible.

I only have access to the data through the javascript since my colleges are creating the files and they don't know about things like encoding. These are posted to a place I can only read from.

Comment: How are you reading them? XMLHttpRequest?

Comment: Have you tried setting the MIME type explicitly? `.mimeType("text/csv; charset=ISO-8859-1")` on the request.

Comment: Ah. I'm using the 'd3.dsv(fieldSeparator, "text/plain");' method.
I'll try that in there though.

Comment: @LarsKotthoff d3.dsv(fieldSeparator, "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1"); worked great!

Write that as an answer and I'll give you a check mark and "up" it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can specify the mime type and content encoding explicitly, e.g.

```
d3.dsv(fieldSeparator, "text/plain; charset=ISO-8859-1");
```