# (d3.js force directed graph) Cannot create property 'vx', but this happens in localhost only

Tags: javascript, d3.js, d3-force-directed

I was tidying up the folder structure (moving the JS to `.js` file instead of inline, and putting it to its own folder) when this suddenly happens. My force directed graph suddenly is having this weird problem. All the nodes and links moved into the top left of the screen. It looks like this:

[image]

The Javascript console says `Cannot create property 'vx' on string 'dki'`.

Oddly enough when I tried to paste the whole code in jsfiddle, it's working as usual. You can find the fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/k6pf1hfw/1/

Here is the JS code:

```js
var nodes = [
  {  id: "pusat",  group: 0,  label: "Pusat",  level: 0 },

  {  id: "dki",  group: 1,  label: "Prov. DKI",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "jaksel",  group: 1,  label: "Kota Jakarta Selatan",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "jakpus",  group: 1,  label: "Kota Jakarta Pusat",  level: 2},
  {  id: "jabar",  group: 2,  label: "Prov. Jawa Barat",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "sumedang",  group: 2,  label: "Kab. Sumedang",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "bekasi",  group: 2,  label: "Kota Bekasi",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "bandung",  group: 2,  label: "Kota Bandung",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "jatim",  group: 3,  label: "Prov. Jawa Timur",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "malang",  group: 3,  label: "Kota Malang",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "lamongan",  group: 3,  label: "Kota Lamongan",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "diy",  group: 4,  label: "Prov. DIY",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "sleman",  group: 4,  label: "Kab. Sleman",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "jogja",  group: 4,  label: "Kota Yogyakarta",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "bali",  group: 5,  label: "Prov. Bali",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "bali1",  group: 5,  label: "Kota Denpasar",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "bali2",  group: 5,  label: "Kab. Buleleng",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "ntt",  group: 6,  label: "Prov. NTT",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "ntt1",  group: 6,  label: "Kab. Alor",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "ntt2",  group: 6,  label: "Kab. Manggarai Timur",  level: 2},
  {  id: "ntb",  group: 7,  label: "Prov. NTB",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "kabima",  group: 7,  label: "Kab. Bima",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "kobima",  group: 7,  label: "Kota Bima",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "kaltara",  group: 8,  label: "Prov. Kaltara",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "kubar",  group: 8,  label: "Kab. Kutai Barat",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "kutim",  group: 8,  label: "Kab. Kutai Timur",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "kaltim",  group: 9,  label: "Prov. Kaltim",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "bpp",  group: 9,  label: "Kota Balikpapan",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "samarinda",  group: 9,  label: "Kota Samarinda",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "kalsel",  group: 10,  label: "Prov. Kalsel",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "banjar",  group: 10,  label: "Kota Banjarmasin",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "tapin",  group: 10,  label: "Kab. Tapin",  level: 2 },
  {  id: "kalbar",  group: 11,  label: "Prov. Kalbar",  level: 1 },
      {  id: "melawi",  group: 11,  label: "Kab. Melawi",  level: 2 },
      {  id: "sambas",  group: 11,  label: "Kab. Sambas",  level: 2}
]

var links = [
  // Pusat-Provinsi
  { source:"pusat", target:"dki", strength:.5, value:100000000000  },
  { source:"pusat", target:"jabar", strength:.5, value:30000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"jatim", strength:.5, value:100000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"diy", strength:.5, value:1000000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"bali", strength:.5, value:10000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"ntt", strength:.5, value:1000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"ntb", strength:.5, value:1000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"kaltim", strength:.5, value:5000000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"kaltara", strength:.5, value:5000000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"kalsel", strength:.5, value:10000000000000},
  { source:"pusat", target:"kalbar", strength:.5, value:1000000000},

  // Provinsi-Kab/Kota
  { source:"dki", target:"jaksel", strength:.7, value:2000000000},
  { source:"dki", target:"jakpus", strength:.7, value:4000000000000},
  { source:"jabar", target:"sumedang", strength:.7, value:400000000000},
  { source:"jabar", target:"bekasi", strength:.7, value:40000000000},
  { source:"jabar", target:"bandung", strength:.7, value:40000000000},
  { source:"jatim", target:"malang", strength:.7, value:300000000000},
  { source:"jatim", target:"lamongan", strength:.7, value:100000000000},
  { source:"diy", target:"sleman", strength:.7, value:4500000000000},
  { source:"diy", target:"jogja", strength:.7, value:6700000000000},
  { source:"bali", target:"bali1", strength:.7, value:100000000000000},
  { source:"bali", target:"bali2", strength:.7, value:2400000000000},
  { source:"ntt", target:"ntt1", strength:.7, value:60000000000000},
  { source:"ntt", target:"ntt2", strength:.7, value:100000000000},
  { source:"ntb", target:"kabima", strength:.7, value:126000000000},
  { source:"ntb", target:"kobima", strength:.7, value:1000000000000},
  { source:"kaltara", target:"kubar", strength:.7, value:12420000000000},
  { source:"kaltara", target:"kutim", strength:.7, value:14400000000000},
  { source:"kaltim", target:"bpp", strength:.7, value:1470000000000},
  { source:"kaltim", target:"samarinda", strength:.7, value:1000000000000000},
  { source:"kalsel", target:"banjar", strength:.7, value:137000000000},
  { source:"kalsel", target:"tapin", strength:.7, value:5050000000000},
  { source:"kalbar", target:"melawi", strength:.7, value:2400000000000},
  { source:"kalbar", target:"sambas", strength:.7, value:5500000000000}
];

function getNeighbors(node) {
  return links.reduce(function(neighbors, link) {
    if (link.target.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.source.id)
    } else if (link.source.id === node.id) {
      neighbors.push(link.target.id)
    }
    return neighbors
  }, [node.id])
}

function isNeighborLink(node, link) {
  return link.target.id === node.id || link.source.id === node.id
}


function getNodeColor(node, neighbors) {
  // If is neighbor
  if (Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1) {
    return 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
    // return node.level === 1 ? '#9C4A9C' : 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)'
  } else {
    // Check the node level
      if (node.level === 0) {
        return '#E72148'
      } else if (node.level === 1) {
        return '#9C4A9C'
      } else {
        return '#D8ABD8'
      }
  }
  //return node.level === 0 ? '#91007B' : '#D8ABD8'
}

function getLinkColor(node, link) {
  return isNeighborLink(node, link) ? 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 1)' : 'rgba(251, 130, 30, 0.25)'
}

function getTextColor(node, neighbors) {
  return Array.isArray(neighbors) && neighbors.indexOf(node.id) > -1 ? '#333' : '#bbb'
}

var width = window.innerWidth
var height = window.innerHeight

var svg = d3.select('svg')
// svg.attr('width', width).attr('height', height)
    svg.attr("width", '100%')
    .attr("height", '500px')
    .attr('viewBox', '250 0 800 600')
    //.attr('viewBox','0 0 '+Math.min(width,height)+' '+Math.min(width,height))
    .attr('preserveAspectRatio','xMidYMid')
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + "," + Math.min(width,height) / 2 + ")");

//add zoom capabilities
  var zoom_handler = d3.zoom()
      .scaleExtent([1 / 2, 8])
      .on("zoom", zoom_actions);

  zoom_handler(svg);

  function zoom_actions(){
      g.attr("transform", d3.event.transform)
  }

  function button_zoom_in(){
      zoom_handler.scaleBy(svg, 2);
  }
  function button_zoom_out(){
      zoom_handler.scaleBy(svg, 0.5);
  }

// simulation setup with all forces
var linkForce = d3
  .forceLink()
  .id(function (link) { return link.id })
  // Alternative: using the distance from the data "strength"
  //.distance(50).strength(function (link) { return link.strength })
  // If don't want to use this, use default here:
  .distance(50).strength(.7)

var simulation = d3
  .forceSimulation()
  .force('link', linkForce)
  .force('charge', d3.forceManyBody().strength(-1500))
  .force('radial', d3.forceRadial(function(d) {
    return d.level * 50
  }, width / 2, height / 2))
  .force('center', d3.forceCenter(width / 2, height / 2))

var dragDrop = d3.drag().on('start', function(node) {
  node.fx = node.x
  node.fy = node.y
}).on('drag', function(node) {
  simulation.alphaTarget(0.7).restart()
  node.fx = d3.event.x
  node.fy = d3.event.y
}).on('end', function(node) {
  if (!d3.event.active) {
    simulation.alphaTarget(0)
  }
  node.fx = null
  node.fy = null
})

function selectNode(selectedNode) {
  var neighbors = getNeighbors(selectedNode)

  // we modify the styles to highlight selected nodes
  nodeElements.attr('fill', function(node) {
    return getNodeColor(node, neighbors)
  })
  textElements.attr('fill', function(node) {
    return getTextColor(node, neighbors)
  })
  linkElements.attr('stroke', function(link) {
    return getLinkColor(selectedNode, link)
  })
}



// Enables zooming
var g = svg.append("g")
    .attr("class", "everything");
// Enables zooming end

// Create circling orbit
var circles = g.selectAll(null)   // use g.selectAll instead of svg.selectAll to enable zoom
  .data([200,350])  // sets the circle radius
  .enter()
  .append("circle")
  .attr("cx", width/2)
  .attr("cy", height/2)
  .attr("r", d=>d)
  .style("fill", "none")
  .style("stroke", "#ddd");

var linkElements = g.append("g")    // use g.append instead of svg.append to enable zoom
  .attr("class", "links")
  .selectAll("line")
  .data(links)
  .enter().append("line")
  .attr("id",function(d,i) { return "linkId_" + i; })
  .attr("stroke-width", function(link) {
    var linkWidthNormalize = link.value / 1000000000;       // in milyar
                                                            // under assumption that smallest 10 milyar, largest > 40 triliun
    if (linkWidthNormalize >= 40001) {
      return 12;
    } else if (linkWidthNormalize >= 20001 && linkWidthNormalize <= 40000) {
      return 10;
    } else if (linkWidthNormalize >= 9001 && linkWidthNormalize <= 20000) {
      return 8;
    } else if (linkWidthNormalize >= 4001 && linkWidthNormalize <= 9000) {
      return 6;
    } else if (linkWidthNormalize >= 10 && linkWidthNormalize <= 4000) {
      return 4;
    } else {
      return 2;
    }
    // return linkWidthNormalize;
  })
  .attr("stroke", "rgba(251, 130, 30, 0.5)")

var nodeElements = g.append("g")    // use g.append instead of svg.append to enable zoom
  .attr("class", "nodes")
  .selectAll("circle")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("circle")
  .attr("r", 12)
  .attr("fill", getNodeColor)
  .attr("stroke", "#fff")
  .attr('stroke-width', 2)
  .call(dragDrop)
  //.on('click', selectNode)      // alternative
  .on('mouseover', selectNode)

var textElements = g.append("g")    // use g.append instead of svg.append to enable zoom
  .attr("class", "texts")
  .selectAll("text")
  .data(nodes)
  .enter().append("text")
  .text(function(node) {
    return node.label
  })
  .attr("font-size", 10)
  .attr("font-family", "sans-serif")
  .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
  .attr("fill", "#333")
  .attr("style", "font-weight:bold; -webkit-text-stroke: 1px #fff; text-shadow: 3px 3px 0 #fff, -1px -1px 0 #fff, 1px -1px 0 #fff, -1px 1px 0 #fff, 1px 1px 0 #fff")
  .attr("dx", 0)
  .attr("dy", 20)



simulation.nodes(nodes).on('tick', () => {
  nodeElements
    .attr('cx', function(node) {
      return node.x
    })
    .attr('cy', function(node) {
      return node.y
    })
  textElements
    .attr('x', function(node) {
      return node.x
    })
    .attr('y', function(node) {
      return node.y
    })
  linkElements
    .attr('x1', function(link) {
      return link.source.x
    })
    .attr('y1', function(link) {
      return link.source.y
    })
    .attr('x2', function(link) {
      return link.target.x
    })
    .attr('y2', function(link) {
      return link.target.y
    })
})

simulation.force("link").links(links)
```

I can't find anything wrong with the code. I have tried reverting my action (moving back the files to its initial place) but nothing changes. It's still like that.

What's wrong with this? This is getting me crazy.

Comment: I think that is because of copy pasting. (node.x ; Ctrl + v => node.vx ?) Did you check thoroughly ?

Comment: Are you sure you copied everything correctly? When remove the line `  {  id: "dki",  group: 1,  label: "Prov. DKI",  level: 1 },` from your fiddle I get the same error in infinite loop: https://jsfiddle.net/k6pf1hfw/2/

Comment: I checked thoroughly. I used diff to make sure it's exactly the same. In fact, the fiddle is directly copy pasted from my local file. It's "fixed" for now though, I moved the .js file several times and use `<script src="jariungu-sunburst.js"></script>` and somehow it magically works. Frustratingly weird.

Comment: God damn it, it's happening again... I just don't know what's wrong with this.

Comment: I have two files referring to the same fil. One is the one I posted in the fiddle before, the other is this: https://jsfiddle.net/6vbdjuwe/ This one works, the previous one doesn't. I really don't know what the hell is happening.

Comment: Found the culprit! Apparently d3.js cannot read HTML with `iso-8859-1` encoding. At least according to this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048574/d3-js-loading-csv-files-with-iso-8859-1-encoding So the reason why it fails on my end is because I use `iso-8859-1` encoding in the HTML, meanwhile JSFiddle uses `utf-8`. Solved!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I finally found the culprit.

Hopefully this serves a warning to anyone as careless as I am: **d3.js [cannot read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21048574/d3-js-loading-csv-files-with-iso-8859-1-encoding) `iso-8859-1` encoding.** My HTML file was using `iso-8859-1` encoding, meanwhile JSFiddle is using `utf-8`. That's why it works in JSFiddle but doesn't in my end.

So changing this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1">
```

to this:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
```

fixed the problem.